# Dropdown menu items spread across white space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to create a drop down menu, where the top level menu items are spread across the entire width of the page, with the left one being aligned to the left side, the right one being aligned to the right side and the items in-between are spread across the white space between the first and left menu item.

I know how to do this by fixed widths, such as menu item 1 takes up 20% of the page width if there are 5 menu items.

But the look I need to accomplish for a job needs to have the same amount of padding between each menu item no matter how many characters they have.  The menu items vary from 4 to 20 characters long.

I was thinking display table on the UL, and Display Table-Cell on the LI elements would create the look I am going for, but it will not recognize any width.  The menu will always be as wide as each menu item put together.  If I add padding of say 15 px between each menu item, the menu will always be the width of all menu items plus the 15 px padding between each one and never stretch across the whole page.

Where to start to design a menu like this?  It also has to be able to work for however many menu items are in it.

Edit:

Here is an example of the current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/RenegadeMonster/hj5unsk9/4/

And here is the CSS code as apparently I can't just link to jsfiddle without accompanied code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.navMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
        $('.navMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
        
        function openSubMenu() {
            $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');    
        };
        
        function closeSubMenu() {
            $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
        };
                   
    });
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    display: table;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  display:table;
  background:rgba(42,46,38,0.9);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.nav_menu {
 margin-left:27px;
 margin-right:27px;
}

.navMenu {
 display: table-cell;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.navMenu ul {
 display:table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 margin-left: -15px;
}

.navMenu li {
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif #111;
 display:table-cell;
}

.navMenu li a:link,.navMenu li a:visited {
 display:table-cell;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin:0;
 color:#dfcc9f;
 font-size:18px;
 display:block;
 padding:15px;
}

.navMenu li a:hover {
 color:#fcb713;
 background-color:#262623;
}
.navMenu li a:active {
 color:#dfcc9f;
 border-bottom: solid 4px #262623;
}
a:active {
    background-color: #FF704D;
}

/*style the sub menu*/
.navMenu li ul {
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.navMenu li ul li {
 display:inline;
 float:none;
}

.navMenu li ul li a:link,.navMenu li ul li a:visited {
 background:#312f2a;
/* The Fallback */
 background:rgba(49,47,42,0.9);
 color:#dfcc9f;
 width:auto;
 font-size:14px;
}

.navMenu li ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#c1a373;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-wrapper">
                <div class="nav_menu">
                    <ul class="navMenu">

                        <li>
                            <a id="home" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Menu Item Number 2</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Example</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Example Menu Item 2</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Monday</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Friday</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">The Weekend</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Jimmy Buffet</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Rock Bands</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">sub menu item 1</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">sub menu item 2</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">sub menu item 3</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">sub menu item 4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Event Planner</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact The Who</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code you currently have. Use http://jsfiddle.net to create a simplified demonstration would help

Comment: Have you looked into [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)? Also as far as the padding messing with your widths, you should try setting the `box-sizing` css property to `border-box`.

Comment: Try using div blocks instead of list elements which off the top of my head I don't think you can put a width on

Comment: Added a dumb down version of my code that only shows the menu.

Comment: I added my code above

I would love to be able to use CSS Flexbox, but I must maintain code that is IE 8 compatible.  Which Flexbox certainly is not.

Comment: Could you explain the issue again in simple terms, I got lost in your explanation. Also your list items are floating left, if you are going to use table cell display then get rid of the float left

Comment: I want the first menu item to be aligned with the left edge, the last menu item to be aligned to the right edge and every menu item between to fill the available space and have a equal amount of white space between each item.

Comment: @ChrisDuCharme like https://jsfiddle.net/hj5unsk9/6/ ? https://jsfiddle.net/hj5unsk9/7/ without the -15px margin left

Comment: @Huangism Not quite, that looks to be using fixed width columns.  I need there to bet equal space between each item so the column width is decided on the width of the the text per each menu item.  The right menu item also has to be aligned with the right edge.

Comment: @ChrisDuCharme then remove the width on the `li`. The cell on the left is flush to the left, the cell on the right i flush to the right, you can see this when inspecting/hovering. If you want to text to be aligned on the right then use `text-align: right` in the css for the last child https://jsfiddle.net/hj5unsk9/13/

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/hj5unsk9/14/, I have removed your table logic. its not needed as long as you are able to give width in % to the menu items.

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  background:rgba(42,46,38,0.9);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.nav_menu {
    margin:0
}

.navMenu {
    margin:0 -15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}

.navMenu ul {
    display:block;
}

.navMenu li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif #111;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center
}

.navMenu li a:link,.navMenu li a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0;
    color:#dfcc9f;
    font-size:18px;
    display:block;
    padding:15px;

}

.navMenu li a:hover {
    color:#fcb713;
    background-color:#262623;
}
.navMenu li a:active {
    color:#dfcc9f;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #262623;
}
a:active {
    background-color: #FF704D;
}

/*style the sub menu*/
.navMenu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top:72px;
}

.navMenu li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:none;
}

.navMenu li ul li a:link,.navMenu li ul li a:visited {
    background:#312f2a;
/* The Fallback */
    background:rgba(49,47,42,0.9);
    color:#dfcc9f;
    width:auto;
    font-size:14px;
}

.navMenu li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#c1a373;
}
```

Comment: That seems to work as long as every thing has a fixed width.  And I may end up just doing that.  However, I was hoping there was a way to do this without having every thing 20%.  That way the longer menu items can take up more space when the browser window is narrower without staking up on 2 lines while on smaller resolutions.